# SAS Assignment Statement and Conditional Execution

Tags: sas

I recently started to learn assignment statement and conditional execution for the SAS program. I am still a beginner. I got a few questions to do, but I am really stuck. I need help.

Given a character variable Y of length 1, create a new variable X7 storing values as defined in the table:

```
 Y                     X8
'E'                  'East'
'S'                  'South'
'W'                  'West'
'N'                  'North'
Other value            ''
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding the question a bit here, but it looks like you are simply wanting to make a new variable based on certain predefined conditions.  If that's your goal, there are countless ways to do this.  Since you're say you're new to SAS, I'll give two essential answers to that question:

Straight forward conditional IF Then Else statements:

```
data test; 
  input Y $1.; 

    length x7 $5; 
          if Y="E" then X7="East"; 
     else if Y="S" then x7="South"; 
     else if Y="W" then x7="West"; 
     else if Y="N" then x7="North"; 
     else x7="";   

   datalines4;
E
N
S
E
_
W
?
;;;;
run;
proc print data=test; 
run;
```

Note: without the length statement, x7 will default to the length of its first input. In this case $4.

Another essential technique in SAS is using formats:

First create your format.  (if its a small list a simple value statement will work fine, otherwise look into the cntlin= option on the format procedure):

```
proc format;
 Value $DI 
 'E'='East'
 'S'='South'
 'W'='West'
 'N'='North'
 Other=' ';
 run;
```

then within a data step you can apply using put() function;

```
data test2; 
  set test;
   x7_2=put(y,$di.); 
 run; 
proc print data=test2; run;
```

Hope that gets you on your way.
If I misunderstood, please clarify.
Thanks!
b